# Jasper + Struts2 Multiple reports in one action

Tags: struts2, jasper-reports

In struts.xml file

```
<action name="myJasperTest" class="com.sample.SupplierEnquiryReport">
            <result name="success" type="jasper">
                <param name="location">/reports/xyz.jasper</param>
                <param name="dataSource">myList</param>
                <param name="format">PDF</param>
            </result>
        </action>
```

I need to return multiple pdf files after one action.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

No, but from your UI JSP you can:

1. open multiple actions, each one returning a PDF;
2. open another JSP, with multiple `<iframe>`, each one pointing (with `src` attribute) to a different Action (or better, to the same, but passing different parameters), and returning a PDF.

Then several pages each one with a PDF, or a big page with several iframes, each iframe with a PDF.